# Book series from Forgotten Realms about siblings who are members of the city guard who solve crimes

Tags: story-identification, books, forgotten-realms

Book series from Forgotten Realms, written in the late 1970s through 1980s.

I think about a brother/sister who are members of the city guard who solve crimes? Sorry about the limited details but I was around 9 or 10 years old when I read the series.

Comment: Maybe the Songs & Swords trilogy? Not siblings or in a city guard but a male/female crime/mystery solving pairing.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  How confident are you that this was Forgotten Realms?  AFAICT the earliest book in the milieu was 1987.

Comment: As @DavidW says, the first Forgotten Realms novel, *Darkwalker on Moonshae*, was not published until 1987.  The only Dungeons & Dragons novel from the 1970s was *Quag Keep* by Andre Norton; there were no other novels until the beginning of the *DRAGONLANCE Chronicles* series in 1983.